# MDC-Web: Multiple simple menu

Tags: web, material-components, material-components-web

I use google MATERIAL COMPONENTS FOR THE WEB and have problems with the "Simple Menu". Check my codepen: [Multiple menus per page?][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/govRmg
```

The first menu works, the others do not.
What do I have to do to have multiple menus per page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) for menu and toggle, but it will return only the first node elements matching “.mdc-simple-menu” and “.js--toggle-dropdown” respectively.

Instead, you should use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) that will return the NodeList, which you’ll need to [convert to array to iterate with its elements](https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9).

I wrapped your example menus and toggles into containers for selecting toggles easier with [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement).

So, the final result might look like this:

```
const menuEls = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-simple-menu'));

menuEls.forEach((menuEl) => {
  // Initialize MDCSimpleMenu on each ".mdc-simple-menu"
  const menu = new mdc.menu.MDCSimpleMenu(menuEl);

  // We wrapped menu and toggle into containers for easier selecting the toggles
  const dropdownToggle = menuEl.parentElement.querySelector('.js--dropdown-toggle');
  dropdownToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.open = !menu.open;
  });
});
```

You can [view the demo on Codepen](https://codepen.io/rustemgareev/pen/dJdEBE?editors=1010).